# Keras evaluate_generator computes more steps than the number indicated in "steps" parameter

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, generator

I am working with a custom generator that yields videos. I'm trying to do a simple evaluation with evaluate_generator on my model, but I realized that changing the batch_size was yielding different accuracy results. I decided to print the yielded video names at each generator step, and it turned out that somehow, the generator is being called more times than what I indicate on the `step` parameter of evaluate_generator.

From what I understand, `evaluate_generator`'s `step` parameter indicates the number of batches to yield. In my case, my generator has a `batch_size` of 10, and because there are 30 datapoints to evaluate, I set `steps=3`. I should then be evaluating my model on all available data points, in 3 steps of 10 points each. However, the generator yields more videos than that, looping back over already analyzed videos and thus affecting the final accuracy score. Here is what's happening in code:

First, my generator (simplified):

```
def video_generator(batch_size=1,files=None,shuffle=True,augment=None,load_func='hmdb_npy_rgb',preprocess_func=None,is_train=True):


L=len(files)

print('Calling video_generator. Batch size: ',batch_size,'. Number of files received:',L,'. Augmentation: ',augment)


## This line is just to make the generator infinite, keras needs that
while True:

    ## Define starting idx for batch slicing
    batch_start = 0
    batch_end = batch_size
    c=1

    ## Loop over the txt file while there are enough unseen files for one more batch
    while batch_start < L:

        ## LOAD DATA
        limit = min(batch_end, L)

        # DEBUG STRING
        print('STEP',c,' - yielding', limit-batch_start,'videos.')

        X = load_func(files[batch_start:limit])
        Y = load_labels(files[batch_start:limit])

        ## PREPROCESS DATA
        if preprocess_func is not None:
            X = preprocess_func(X, is_train=is_train)

        ## AUGMENT DATA
        if augment is not None:
            X= augment_video_batch(X, augment)

        ## YIELD DATA
        yield X,Y #a tuple with two numpy arrays with batch_size samples

        ## Increasing idxs for next batch
        batch_start += batch_size
        batch_end += batch_size
        c+=1
```

As you can see, it's a pretty standard generator. I am printing a debug string at every step, to see how many times the main loop is called. This is my general code:

```
for k,v in classes_to_evaluate.items():
  # k is a class of videos, e.g. jump, run, etc
  # v is a list of video names corresponding to class k

  print('Evaluating',k, '. # steps:' 3)

  generator=video_generator(files = v, batch_size=batch_size, **gen_params)

  metrics = model.evaluate_generator(generator, steps=3,
            max_queue_size=10, workers=1, use_multiprocessing=False)

  print('Time elapsed on',k,':', end-start)
```

Based on this, I should be seeing the following prints:

```
Evaluating shoot_gun . num steps: 3
Calling video_generator. Batch size:  10 . Number of files received:  30 . Augmentation:  None
STEP 1  - yielding 10  videos.
STEP 2  - yielding 10  videos.
STEP 3  - yielding 10  videos.
Time elapsed on shoot_gun : # time elapsed here
```

However, this is what I'm seeing:

```
Evaluating shoot_gun . num steps: 3
Calling video_generator. Batch size:  10 . Number of files received:  30 . Augmentation:  None
STEP 1  - yielding 10  videos.
STEP 2  - yielding 10  videos.
STEP 3  - yielding 10  videos.
STEP 1  - yielding 10  videos.
STEP 2  - yielding 10  videos.
STEP 3  - yielding 10  videos.
Time elapsed on shoot_gun : 7.721895118942484
```

And the number of steps gets kind of randomized for the other classes. As you can see, the generator nters the loop **6 times instead of 3** for class shoot_gun, but then for some classes I get 4 steps, for other classes 5 steps (and all classes have exactly 30 videos, and are called with a new instance of the same generator). For example:

```
Evaluating climb . num steps: 3
Calling video_generator. Batch size:  10 . Number of files received:  30 . Augmentation:  None
STEP 1  - yielding 10  videos.
STEP 2  - yielding 10  videos.
STEP 3  - yielding 10  videos.
STEP 1  - yielding 10  videos.
STEP 2  - yielding 10  videos.
Time elapsed on climb : 7.923485273960978
```

Here, as you can see, I get 5 generator steps instead of the 3 that I want.
But then:

```
Evaluating kiss . num steps: 3
Calling video_generator. Batch size:  10 . Number of files received:  30 . Augmentation:  None
STEP 1  - yielding 10  videos.
STEP 2  - yielding 10  videos.
STEP 3  - yielding 10  videos.
STEP 1  - yielding 10  videos.
Time elapsed on kiss : 9.742703797062859
```

Here, I get only 4 steps. I don't understand, as there are no differences in the batch-size, number of videos or any other parameter between classes. It is important to note that in NO CASE do I get only 3 steps, as the intended behavior should be.

Does anyone know why this happens, and how to make it at least consistent?